# Cryptic images have been posted around University of Central Florida campus. Can you help crack the cipher?

Tags: cipher, visual, real

Recently there have been sightings of images duct-taped to various poles and such, reminiscent of a large house with windows within the UCF campus. On closer inspection, there is obviously a cryptic message hidden within the windows, most likely in a sequence.

See two of these images below:

[image: First example of the messages.]

[image]

The 2x3 nature of the windows would point to something like [Braille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille); however, this is obviously not the case as there are too many invalid characters.

**Does anyone have any other ideas as to what this could be?**

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six-bit_character_code might help.

Comment: Not an answer because this is more what it isn't, but you can read 2x8 or 1x16 bit values across each row. However, whether black is 0 or 1 these do not result in anything useful in ASCII or UTF-16. (I got briefly excited when one of the sets starts off "Ja!" but that appears to be a coincidence.)

Comment: One thing that also stands out is the last 4 windows of the second image. If the blank window is in-fact a period, then those 4 windows could very well be a domain extension such as ".com" or ".net".

Comment: Any information on the real building on the campus this is depicting?

Comment: Do all the pictures begin with the same two symbols that these two begin with?

Comment: Also it seems kind of weird that the pictures seem to be mounted (but not centrally) on a larger piece of board or card. Is it possible this is some sort of treasure hunt where students might get clues to the symbols as they take part?

Comment: Also, if you could post pictures of more of the images then they might be amenable to a frequency analysis. (I am way too invested in this given that I live thousands of miles away from UCF and have no connection to it :-D )

Comment: I don't think the .com / .net (or .edu) theory holds water. None of those characters appear anywhere else in either of the two images and I can't believe there are no other Os or Es anywhere else.

Comment: I also note that the buildings have 4-digit IDs (although they all begin with 0) and alphanumeric labels, some of which are 4 characters: https://guides.ucf.edu/statistics-ucf/buildinginventory. Could each image encode 4 building labels?

Comment: You can write English in Braille, and then you can write in [English Braille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Braille). And I mean "you" in a very, very passive sense, that writing system is way too quirky for any sane person.

Comment: @Bass that is interesting, but I don't think it can be the answer - the top picture translates as "and wh cc bb r y with s" / "wh . in th c ea o gg".

Comment: May be this is a Cardan grille? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardan_grille

Comment: Further, I don't think this can be an alphabetic substitution cipher. There are simply too few repeated characters. Other possibilities - could it be something where you have to overlay multiple images to black out all squares? Could it be pieces of a crossword puzzle that have to be fitted together?

Comment: Or pieces of a picture that fit together (like a jigsaw)?

Comment: This looks a lot like Hexahue used in Geocaching https://www.boxentriq.com/code-breaking/hexahue

Comment: Well, I *was* quite invested in this but when the OP doesn't come back and update / answer comments it's hard to stay interested.

Comment: What is posted is all the information I can provide. If there was anything else I would have posted it on the OP.

Answer (score 2):

> It's a [VuMark](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/VuMark.html).
> VuMarks are used by Vuforia applications, and behave somewhat similar to QR codes. They contain data that can only be deciphered by one application, that has been built with the original SVG. The difference is that VuMarks are customizable by adding a design area, and by making the data part as custom shapes.

Comment: Welcome to PSE! It could actually be a VuMark but what is the coded message?

Comment: @melfnt Good question. They are meant to be customizable, so there is no standard way to decipher it. But Vuforia's website has some examples of templates, and this image is vaguely similar to it, it might be possible that they used the example. If this is the case, there is a library for Unity Engine that can decipher them from the template. But they are meant to be undecipherable by anything else.

Comment: Oh wow, well spotted. One of the examples on the VuMark page you linked to looks exactly like these. However, it's way beyond my available time to implement an app to decipher / decode... would be very interested if anyone else has the time to do so! Welcome to PSE.